# How do you make git tortoise and visual studio work on a git repository inside wsl2?

Tags: visual-studio, wsl2, tortoise-git

How do you make git tortoise and visual studio work on a git repository inside wsl2? I git pulled a repo inside my WSL2 Ubuntu instance, but because the application tortoise and visual studio are inside my Windows instance, and I need to access it through a network drive (WSL2 virtual drive), searching through a file, or getting the git history of a file or folder through tortoise takes a very long time. Is there a way to speed things up?